# Make a list of Car Plates

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to extract a list of car plates which have passed through a certain point. I am asked to list the plates which are not domestic.

I have come up with this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customers 
WHERE PlakaNo LIKE '[012345678]%' 
and PlakaNo LIKE '__[A-Z]%'
```

The domestic plate order is like one of these:

```
99 X 9999
99 X 99999
99 XX 999
99 XX 9999
99 XXX 99
99 XXX 999
```

(PlakaNo is a plate number)

Comment: Apparently you are reading from a database, so please tag your dbms

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: Why to do this in pure SQL? Of course it's possible, but such things are often much easier in your application. For example, linq is quite good in such checks.

Comment: The plate order is like : "99 X 9999", "99 X 99999"
"99 XX 999", "99 XX 9999"
"99 XXX 99" or"99 XXX 999"  I have tried all solutions but I still get "No result".

Comment: @UğurHalis I have edited my answer in case you wanted spaces between your first 2 digits and some alphabets, and then again a space between those alphabets and the last numbers. Examples of SQL Server, PostgreSQL and MySQL databases are included. Do you know what database you are using? RF1991 and Hans were asking about that also.

Comment: I am informed that I will need to write the code in SQL and the database is a Oracle db. I have not seen the DB yet. The real life format has spaces between plate numbers and letters but I am not sure how these have been transferred into the database. I will have a test of some kind for a job and I am trying to be ready for questions they might ask. Really appreciate all of yours' helps.

Comment: @UğurHalis I have added an example of Oracle 21c that you might find helpful. Once you look through all the answers provided, I recommend that you mark one of them accepted to put a closure to your question. There's a little check mark by all the answers. Click on any of the answers' check mark you like.

Comment: @zedfoxus Thank you very much. I checked a mark above, I hope I have selected the right one.

Comment: @UğurHalis all is well. I believe your question is being edited for formatting by someone. Once the formatting changes are accepted by others, I'll recommend you add a tag called `Oracle` to it so that others reviewing the question can recognize that this question is regarding Oracle database. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your requirements of having:

- 2 numbers in front
- then 1,2 or 3 letters
- then, 2,3,4 or 5 numbers in the end

The combinations you are looking for are:

```
##A##      ##AA##      ##AAA##
##A###     ##AA###     ##AAA###
##A####    ##AA####    ##AAA####
##A#####   ##AA#####   ##AAA#####
```

The shortest license plate will be 5 character long and the longest will be 10. You can always include in your query something like `where length(PlakaNo) between 5 and 10` or something like that in addition to the regex.

You can do something like this:

## Oracle 21c

```
select * from customers
where regexp_like(PlakaNo, '^[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1,3}[0-9]{2,5}$');
```

If you want spaces in your license plates to match, try:

```
select * from customers
where regexp_like(PlakaNo, '^[0-9]{2}[[:space:]][A-Za-z]{1,3}[[:space:]][0-9]{2,5}$');
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/yolYwnmh

## SQL Server 2022

```
select PlakaNo
from customers
where PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
;
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/OiESyle8

## PostgreSQL 14

```
select PlakaNo
from customers
where PlakaNo ~ '^[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1,3}[0-9]{2,5}$'
;
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/rAvrGKnx

## MySQL 8

```
select PlakaNo
from customers
where PlakaNo regexp '^[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1,3}[0-9]{2,5}$'
;
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/mQUvaIU7

## Sample

```
create table customers (PlakaNo varchar(20));
insert into customers values
('smal'), ('too long info'), ('1BAD2'),
('12A12'), ('12A123'), ('12A1234'),
('12BB12'), ('12BB123'), ('12BB1234'), ('12BB12345'),
('12CCC12'), ('12CCC123'), ('12CCC1234'), ('12CCC12345'),
('12DDDD12'), ('12DDDD123'), ('12DDDD1234'), ('12DDDD12345');
```

## Result

```
12A12
12A123
12A1234
12BB12
12BB123
12BB1234
12BB12345
12CCC12
12CCC123
12CCC1234
12CCC12345
```

## Explanation

`[0-9]` will match a number. `[0-9][0-9]` matches 2 numbers. In databases that allow some more flexibility, you can do `[0-9]{2}` means exactly 2 digits.

`^` means begin matching at the start of the data.

`$` means match till the end of the data.

`'^[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1,3}[0-9]{2,5}$'` means, from the start of the data I want a digit {2} times, followed by either a capitalized alphabet or lower case alphabet 1, 2 or 3 times, followed by a digit 2, 3, 4 or 5 times.

Hope this helps.

---

## EDIT

If you want spaces like this between your plate numbers,

```
## A ##      ## AA ##      ## AAA ##
## A ###     ## AA ###     ## AAA ###
## A ####    ## AA ####    ## AAA ####
## A #####   ## AA #####   ## AAA #####
```

then you can use these kinds of queries:

## Oracle 21c

```
select * from customers
where regexp_like(PlakaNo, '^[0-9]{2}[[:space:]][A-Za-z]{1,3}[[:space:]][0-9]{2,5}$');
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/yolYwnmh

## SQL Server using space in the regular expression (regex)

```
select PlakaNo
from customers
where PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9] [A-Za-z] [0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9] [A-Za-z] [0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9] [A-Za-z] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9] [A-Za-z] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9] [A-Za-z][A-Za-z] [0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9] [A-Za-z][A-Za-z] [0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9] [A-Za-z][A-Za-z] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9] [A-Za-z][A-Za-z] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9] [A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z] [0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9] [A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z] [0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9] [A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  or PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9] [A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
;
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/ndgfZBXB

## PostgreSQL

```
select PlakaNo
from customers
where PlakaNo ~ '^[0-9]{2} [A-Za-z]{1,3} [0-9]{2,5}$'
;
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/eplGmji3

## MySQL

```
select PlakaNo
from customers
where PlakaNo regexp '^[0-9]{2} [A-Za-z]{1,3} [0-9]{2,5}$'
;
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/sVb1ENui

Comment: That's a very good explained answer (upvoted), but it's astounding the query for SQL Server looks so long and "complicated". Are you sure there is no "shortcut" like in the other DBMS you have mentioned?

Comment: @JonasMetzler thank you. I don't know of a shorter way to write the regex in SQL Server. When I started writing the answer, I sketched out the pattern on paper and then did it the long way with SQL Server to ensure it'd give me results I was hoping for. Then, when I did the same with PostgreSQL, I remembered I could shorten the regex. Then I began looking for a better way to do it with SQL Server and didn't find anything quickly. So, I wrapped up the answer and called it good.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PostgreSQL, you can use the [`~` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) in order to match from a regex.

Then, concerning your regex, you can do :

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE PlakaNo ~ '^\d{2}[A-Z]{1,3}\d{2,5}$';
```

[SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c1266/1)

Details :

- ^ asserts position at start of a line
- \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
- {2} matches the previous token exactly 2 times
- A-Z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
- {1,3} matches the previous token between 1 and 3 times
- \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
- {2,5} matches the previous token between 2 and 5 times
- $ asserts position at the end of a line

Answer (score 1):

Using just SQL wildcards:

```
select * from Plates where
      PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9][A-Z]%[0-9][0-9]'           -- skeleton format
  and PlakaNo not like '%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%'           -- 4 consecutive alpha
  and PlakaNo not like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' -- 6 consecutive numeric
  and PlakaNo not like '%[0-9][A-Z]%[0-9][A-Z]%'          -- >2 transitions
```

And similarly, if not slightly more elegant:

```
select * from Plates where
      PlakaNo like '[0-9][0-9][A-Z]%[0-9][0-9]'
  and Plakano not like '___%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%__'
  and PlakaNo not like '___%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%__'
  and PlakaNo not like '___%[0-9][A-Z]%__'
```

This does assume that you've already restricted the inputs to strictly alphanumeric characters.

https://dbfiddle.uk/WXHRVi8z